# How can call to fonts be combined

Tags: php, symfony

I copied google fonts to my local. As it was taking some time to make the call. So before call was this:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,700,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
```

As i moved this to local i copied 3 woff2 files to my local. Now i see that my homepage is making 3 separate calls to woff2 files. Is there a way to create a single woff2 file? Or to make only single call for all woff2 files?

Comment: Why don't you use googlefont CDN?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel - Not aware of it. Do you have any link or example on how to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download the font in order to use it on your homepage. Instead, easily include the `<link>` into your `<html>` structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link src='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,700,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <head>
    <body>
        <style>
            * { font-family: 'Open Sans'; }
            h1 { font-weight: 800; }
            p { font-weight: 300; }
        </style>
        <h1>Headline</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

See a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2fgrg23/).

Comment: I did this at first but the call to google fonts was taking like 1.5 seconds hence the reason i moved fonts to local.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to handle 3+ files, taking a look on https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,700,600,300